# Combobox filter is effected by its labelFunction flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flex4.5

I had a comboBox for which I implemented custom filter and the combobox code looks like this

```
<fx:Declarations>
        <s:ArrayCollection id="arrC">
            <vo:ValueObject firstValue="430" secondValue="sampath"/>
            <vo:ValueObject firstValue="105" secondValue="New York"/>
            <vo:ValueObject firstValue="896" secondValue="Xerox"/>
        </s:ArrayCollection>
    </fx:Declarations>

private function combineFunction(item:Object):String {
                return item.firstValue+"-"+item.secondValue;
            }

<local:AwadComboBox x="325" y="212" id="cb" dataProvider="{arrC}" labelFunction="combineFunction"/>
```

the combobox is implememted using a custom filter which extends the combobox

```
private var unfilteredDataProvider : IList;
            override public function set dataProvider(value:IList):void {
                super.dataProvider = value;

                unfilteredDataProvider = value;
            }

            override protected function textInput_changeHandler(event:TextOperationEvent):void {
                super.textInput_changeHandler(event);

                if (unfilteredDataProvider is ArrayCollection) {
                    ArrayCollection(unfilteredDataProvider).filterFunction = filterMatches;
                    ArrayCollection(unfilteredDataProvider).refresh();

                    super.dataProvider = new ArrayCollection(unfilteredDataProvider.toArray()); 
                }
            }

            protected function filterMatches(item:Object):Boolean {
                if (item is String) {
                    if(String(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(
                        textInput.text.slice(0,
                            textInput.selectionAnchorPosition).toLowerCase())>-1)
                        return true;
                }
                else if (labelField && labelField!= "") {
                    if(item.hasOwnProperty(labelField) && 
                        String(item[labelField]).toLowerCase().indexOf(
                            textInput.text.slice(0,
                                textInput.selectionAnchorPosition).toLowerCase())>-1)
                        return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
```

In this combobox, watever the character you enter, if that character is in the dropdown list, that value should be filtered but there is a bug in my code, can someone please fix this for me.

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you need an AutoComplete component.  Instead of building your own; I recommend using ours: http://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&productID=19 . It used to be a commercial product, but is now open source under the Apache License.

Comment: I appreciate for your response, but i cannot use 3rd party swc for my project, so can you please give me an other way to resolve this?

Comment: You can take the code and build it yourself.  Why can't you use a third party SWC?  Plenty of other folks have done the "hard" work for you.